# How does one indicate the "default" connection string for Enterprise Library?

Tags: enterprise-library

I hant to be able to call DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(), i.e. with no parameter to indicate which connection string to pull from my config file. I only have one connection string in my config file. The only help I have found on the internet is instructions to indicate the default connection string using the Enterprise Library Configuration tool (by right-clicking on my config file in Visual Studio). But from there, I see no way to "select" a connection string or mark it to be the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**YOu should define the dataConfiguration section in your config**

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
<section name="dataConfiguration" ...
```

**And then set the value**

```
<dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="ConnectionStringName" />
```

Comment: Thanks. FYI for others, this tag just needs to be within the main <configuration> tag.

Comment: `<configSections>
    <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
  </configSections>
  <dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="ConnectionStringName" />`